# Is that grammatically correct if I wrote “where is the sense when”

Tags: grammar, questions

I'm writing a song, and I’m not sure if it would be acceptable if I said

> Where’s the sense when you clip the wings of angels?

Is it grammatically correct or not ?

Comment: The gift of creatives is knowing how often to break rules, which you aren't. Capturing how people really speak (colloquial language) lifts poetry and song out of the bookish realm and into art. Your lyric asks the same thing about curtailing creativity.

Answer (score 1):

The word "sense," when used in this manner, is almost always followed by the preposition "in":

> Where’s the sense **in clipping** the wings of angels?

That said, in songwriting one typically cares more about fitting the rhythm and melody than about following the normal rules of grammar and usage.

Comment: +1 "in songwriting one typically cares more about fitting the rhythm and melody than about following the normal rules of grammar and usage."  But for writing songs in English, it helps if you are a native (or at least expert) speaker of English.

Comment: @GEdgar In non-English-speaking countries, songs written in other languages sometimes incorporate phrases in English for effect, [even if those phrases are not grammatically correct](https://schwa.byu.edu/files/2014/11/W2014-Willes2.pdf) and make little sense to native speakers.